# As a novice scientific writer, how can I publish a scientific review?

Tags: publications, writing, review-articles

I like to write and investigate in science; but it is not enough;
 Precisely I want to write a scientific review, as a beginner I don’t know how to publish it;
I don’t have a support, is it possible to publish a scientific review alone and for free?
 Otherwise, do you have any idea how can I find chemists co authors that may accept to work with me;
 Thank you very much in advance for your suggestions;

Comment: (1) Your second paragraph seems like a distinct question to me that you better ask separately (also, what should “international awards support for beginner scientific writers” be? I never heard of something like this). (2) As for your first question: You will likely get better answers if you say a little bit about your experience and qualifications (i.e., scientific degrees), in particular your experience with (reading) scientific literature. (3) Welcome to Academia SE.

Comment: If "international awards support for beginner scientific writers" means you want to actually get paid to write a paper, then you truly know nothing about science writing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Definitely not ,  what I meant : if a funding support in order to publish the scientific review exist. As I mentioned above, I don’t  know exactly how does it work but I know that I must pay the journal in order to publish a review and if  such a funding support exist;  for sure my aim is not to gain money from publishing, (the quality is important) , all what I want is to learn and enjoy learning no more no less.

Comment: “I know that I must pay the journal in order to publish a review” – No, you do not. There are such pay-to-publish journals, but there are also pay-to-view journals, where the reader pays the publishing costs.

Answer (score 2):

Publishing a review on your own can be done.  However, it would be better if you found a senior researcher in your field that you can co-author the manuscript with.  Publishing a review alone may not do much for your professional career (it can even harm your career if it turns out your review is not good enough).  Co-authoring a review with an expert on the subject can be considered highly prestigious and by working with a senior person on this publication, you will learn much more than if you work on your own.